# What's the most efficient way to find matching sequences of cells in two (or more) arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, pattern-matching

**Example 1**

Let's say I have two arrays:

```
('n','v','a','n','i','n','n','v','a','n')
('a','n','n','n','v','a','n','v','n')
```

And I want to find all the matching sequences between the two (maybe above two cells long or so) which aren't sub matches of other longer matches. Here's what I see as matches:

`('n','n','v','a','n')` = position 5 in array 1 and position 3 in array 2

Array 1: ('n','v','a','n','i',**'n','n','v','a','n'**)

Array 2: ('a','n',**'n','n','v','a','n'**,'v','n')

**Example 2**

```
('n','v','a','n','i','n','n','v','i','n')
('a','n','i','n','p','v','i','n','v','n')
```

Here, we have more than one sequence but they are shorter as follows:

`('a','n','i','n')` = position 2 in arraay 1 and position 0 in array 2

`('v','i','n')` = position 7 in array 1 and position 5 in array 2

Array 1: ('n','v',**'a','n','i','n'**,'a',**'v','i','n'**)

Array 2: (**'a','n','i','n'**,'p',**'v','i','n'**,'v','n')

**Summary**

There are more than one matches in both examples, but they all exist within the larger matches in at least one of the arrays.

So what's the most efficient (a balance of low memory and high speed, think mobile devices) code which could achieve this? JavaScript code examples would be awesome!

Comment: If you don't understand my question or it could be made clearer, please comment! Don't just down vote!

Comment: Please post your attempt...What have you tried?

Comment: @brso05 I haven't done any code as of yet... I just have some random things in my head which would be hard to put into words or code. Sorry I've not got much else to show/say!

Comment: Really not cleared...('n','n','v','a','n') = position 5 in array 1 and position 3 in array 2....How can you see this as a matches! put another example to make it clear?

Comment: @PabloMáximo That's intersection of presorted arrays, these arrays will not be sorted (and cannot be). Thanks anyway though!

Comment: `an`, `n` and `v` can also be matched against the second string without being contained in any longer match. Why don't you want them as your result? Your requirements aren't really clear.

Comment: @Bergi "maybe above two cells long or so"

Comment: @Matthew: Ah, I see. Looks like you're facing the [longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem), with the respective solutions.

Comment: @Bergi This is a thing!? Wow... is this going to be a really tricky question to answer then?

Comment: @Matthew: No, there are much trickier problems known to computer science :-)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "efficient?" E.g., fastest, least memory-consuming, fastest/easiest to code? How large are the strings?

Comment: The arrays in the beginning of your "Example 2" do not match the ones at the end of it - the second match should be `nvin`.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Oh, well spotted, fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my JavaScript attempt at the general LCS, `O(mn)` time and space, version. Since we go row by row, space could be reduced by reusing just two rows, copying the second to the first when done.

```js
var example1 = [['n','v','a','n','i','n','n','v','a','n']
               ,['a','n','n','n','v','a','n','v','n']],

    example2 = [['n','v','a','n','i','n','n','v','i','n']
               ,['a','n','i','n','v','i','n','v','n']];

function f(as){
  var M = new Array(as[0].length),
      result = [];

  for (var i=0; i<as[0].length; i++){
    M[i] = new Array(as[1].length).fill(0);

    for (var j=0; j<as[1].length; j++){
      if (as[0][i] == as[1][j]){
        M[i][j] = M[i-1] && M[j-1] ? 1 + M[i-1][j-1] : 1;
      }
      if ((i == as[0].length - 1 || j == as[1].length - 1) && M[i][j] > 2){
        result.push([i - M[i][j] + 1,j - M[i][j] + 1,M[i][j]]);
      } else if (i > 1 && j > 1 && M[i][j] < M[i-1][j-1] && M[i-1][j-1] > 2){
        result.push([i - M[i-1][j-1],j - M[i-1][j-1],M[i-1][j-1]]);
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(example2))); // [[2,0,4],[6,3,4]]
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the [[2,0,4],[6,3,4]] signify.

Comment: @Matthew `2` and `0` are the respective starting indexes of a match, `4` is the match length; `[6,3,4]` is a second match represented in the same way. Those were the matches for example 2.

Comment: Ooooooh... I see! +1 and possibly the answer I've been looking for!

Comment: @Matthew what would be the length of the longest array you'd expect? And if you have more than two, then how many, and would you look for matches that exist only in all arrays at once, or in different combinations (like it would be ok if some matches are in arr2 and arr3, and others in arr1 and arr2, etc.)?

Comment: Ideally, I'd love matches which don't overlap at all and custom minimum and maximum lengths options! But that might be asking for too much!

Comment: @Matthew Would you skip two matches with an overlap or choose one to return; and if so, how would you choose which one?

Comment: I'd not really thought about it! I guess returning either first or the longest would make equal sense. The first would probably be easier too as you could skip ahead instead of having to go back and forget the match if you later find a longer one.

Answer (score 2):

If the two arrays have lengths `m` and `n`, I don't think you can possibly do better than `O(mn)` in the general case. Suppose you have arrays with alternating `a`s but otherwise distinct characters, like this

```
[a, b, a, c, a, d, a, e, a, f, a, g]
[a, h, a, i, a, j, a, k, a, l, a, m]
```

The number of matches is `(m/2)*(n/2)`. If you want to find them all, your algorithm can be at best `O(mn)`.

You can do it in `O(mn)` time as follows. Imagine sliding one array past the other like this:

```
[a, b, c, d, e]
            [f, g, h, i, j]

   [a, b, c, d, e]
            [f, g, h, i, j]

      [a, b, c, d, e]
            [f, g, h, i, j]

                  ...
                        [a, b, c, d, e]
            [f, g, h, i, j]
```

There are `m + n - 1` possible positions. For each position you have to iterate over the pairs of aligned characters (there are at worst `min(m, n)` of these pairs) and find the longest chains of matching characters. This has time complexity

```
O((m + n) * min(m, n)) = O(mn)
```

This solution has the disadvantage that the time taken only really depends on the length of the arrays, not on the contents. For example it still takes `O(nm)` time even if the arrays are equal (when it clearly takes only `O(n)` time to check this and return the one answer). As indicated in the other answer there are much cleverer solutions that will take far less time if the number of matching sequences is small.

Comment: You're right, insofar as you can't do better than O(mn) in general (nice construction).  But you can still do better in the sense of making an output-sensitive algorithm that is O(f(n, m) + k), with f(n, m) being o(mn).

Comment: @j_random_hacker That's true. Do you know what the average time complexity of an `O(f(n, m) + k) ` algorithm is? The above approach has the disadvantage that it basically always takes the same time.

Comment: +1 Although this isn't actual JavaScript code, it does demonstrate a concept (the array sliding bit) which I think I could use to build code around.

Comment: @Matthew I don't know JavaScript at all, so can't help you there, I'm afraid.

Comment: Well, it would depend on f(n, m) (e.g. f(n, m) = O(n+m) for my solution) and also on the distribution of inputs you choose to analyse.  If there is a bound on the number of times a character can appear in a string (or if you assume characters are drawn randomly and independently, and the alphabet is large enough that the expected number of occurrences is "small enough") then you could get k = O(m+n) on average, for linear time overall.

Comment: Also your solution has the advantage of being easy to implement :)

Comment: @PaulBoddington That's not a problem, I know a few languages and can make something based on that sliding thing. Just waiting to see what else comes up.

Comment: @Matthew If you need the most efficient solution I think j_random_hackers's answer is much better than mine. I don't know why it has two downvotes. If I were you I'd wait too - maybe somebody will give hints about how to implement it in javascript.

Comment: @PaulBoddington However, I have no way to implement it; it's all theory and no practical. Yes, it may be more efficient, but it's not a "solution" to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an <strike>O(n)</strike>O(n+k) solution for two strings `A` and `B` whose lengths sum to n, and which have k such maximal matching substrings:

1. Build a [generalised suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree) on your two strings `A` and `B`.  (This is just an ordinary suffix tree on the single string `A$B#`, where `$` and `#` are single characters that don't appear anywhere in either `A` or `B`.)  This can be done in O(n) time using e.g. Ukkonen's algorithm.
2. Perform a bottom-up DFS through this tree that does two things at each node:

   - Determines, and records, whether there is any leaf corresponding to a suffix of `A` below this node, and whether there is any leaf corresponding to a suffix of `B` below this node.  (Exercise: How to answer this question for a leaf?)
   - If leaves of both kinds exist, *and* this is not also true of any child node, then report the substring corresponding to this node as a solution.  (If the condition also holds for some child, then the substring corresponding to this node is a substring of the substring corresponding to that child, and you only want maximal substrings.)

This will also work comfortably for smallish numbers >= 3 of strings: calculate and store the *set* of input strings that have leaves beneath the current node, and "fire" when this set becomes full.

Comment: I have no idea how to code that into Javascript. Care to explain more with examples?

Comment: I hate it when people down vote anonymously too, but maybe they cannot comment yet or something?

Comment: @Matthew: I don't know JS I'm afraid.  There may be existing libraries available.